# Apollo module not calling request sometimes

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-apollo

Hi everyone i have a question.
Im using Nuxtjs + apollo modules
https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module

I have 2 pages 1 for project page & 1 for project update.

The problem is when i'm visiting project page every GQL requests will calling to my laravel server(from mount() ).And then i click on nuxt-link to seconds page, make some change and then click to nuxt-link to go back to first page, my request doesn't call to server again. I need make it call every times i visit to first page. Anyone can give me some solution ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `fetchPolicy` option available in Apollo queries. [The Vue Apollo documentation only briefly mentions the option](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/api/smart-query.html#setoptions), however [the React Apollo are more thorough about your choices](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy) (the options are the same between versions).

The default behavior is `cache-first`. From the React Apollo Docs:

> **cache-first**: This is the default value where we always try reading
>   data from your cache first. If all the data needed to fulfill your
>   query is in the cache then that data will be returned. Apollo will
>   only fetch from the network if a cached result is not available. This
>   fetch policy aims to minimize the number of network requests sent when
>   rendering your component.

You sound like you want `network-only`, again quoting from the React Apollo docs:

> **network-only**: This fetch policy will never return you initial data
>   from the cache. Instead it will always make a request using your
>   network interface to the server. This fetch policy optimizes for data
>   consistency with the server, but at the cost of an instant response to
>   the user when one is available.

So your query on your page will look something like:

```
<script>
export default {
  apollo: {
    project: {
      query: MY_PROJECT_QUERY,
      variables() { return { projectId: this.$route.params.projectId } },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```